# How do I link assembly with the C library with MSVC++ linker?

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, assembly, linker

I found a simple assembly tutorial online that uses some C functions. I've already used NASM to generate a .obj file but I'm having trouble linking against the C library from the command line. How do I do this with link.exe?

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify one of the [run-time library options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx): `/MD` (multithreaded DLL run-time) or `/MT` (multithreaded static run-time).

In debug builds, specify `/MDd` or `/MTd` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turns out that I just wasn't linking to the right file. I was trying to link against MSVCRT.dll and what I needed to link against was MSVCRT.lib.